# Javascript regular expression is returning # character even though it's not captured

Tags: javascript, regex

```
text = 'ticket number #1234 and #8976 ';
r = /#(\d+)/g;

var match = r.exec(text);

log(match); // ["#1234", "1234"]
```

In the above case I would like to capture both 1234 and 8976. How do I do that. Also the sentence can have any number of '#' followed by integers. So the solution should not hard not be hard coded assuming that there will be at max two occurrences.

Update:
Just curious . Checkout the following two cases.

```
var match = r.exec(text); // ["#1234", "1234"]

var match = text.match(r);  //["#1234", "#8976"]
```

Why in the second case I am getting # even though I am not capturing it. Looks like string.match does not obey capturing rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` it multiple times to get the rest.

```
while((match = r.exec(text)))
  log(match);
```

Comment: Better compare to `null`: `while ((match = r.exec(text)) !== null)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var match = text.match(r);
```

That will give you all matches at once (requires *g* flag) instead of one match at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
var text = 'ticket number #1234 and #8976 ';
var r = /#(\d+)/g;

var matches = [];
text.replace( r, function( all, first ) {
    matches.push( first )
});

log(matches);

//  ["1234", "8976"]
```